# How to deal with many possible values to make a query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building an MVC app in which the user will have the possibilities of using a lot of filters to get exactly what he wants.

Here's an overview of those filters based on the controller method:

```
//
// GET: /Card/SearchIndex
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string objName, string objType, string objCostSymbol, string objCost, string powerSymbol,
                                        string powerValue, string ratingSymbol, string ratingValue, string ownerName, string objSet, 
                                        string objRarity, string addCostValue, int? objNumber,
                                        string addCostValue2, string addCostValue3, string addCostValue4, string addCostValue5, string addCostValue6,
                                        bool? blueColor, bool? redColor, bool? yellowColor, bool? purpleColor, bool? greyColor, bool? blackColor,
                                        bool? musicColor, bool? allColor)
        {
             // MORE CODE HERE...
        }
```

I want to know how would be the best way to deal with all these filters, and how could I get a List of objInfo based on the given parameters. Keep in mind that some values may be null. All I've done up to now is load "all" the objInfo I could, then sort them by removing the non-wanted item, which is in my sense "not smart", but I'm new to MVC App and I'm trying to find a better way to do this.

**EDIT**

Here's the view that generates the data:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MvcApp.Models.ObjInfo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SearchIndex";
}

<h2>Objects Management</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New Obj", "Create")
    @using (Html.BeginForm()){
        <p>
            <label>
                Obj Colors : Check a box to search for a color.
            </label>
            All: @Html.CheckBox("allColor", true)<br/>
            Blue: @Html.CheckBox("blueColor", true)
            Red: @Html.CheckBox("redColor", true)
            Yellow: @Html.CheckBox("yellowColor", true) <br/>
            Purple: @Html.CheckBox("purpleColor", true)
            Grey: @Html.CheckBox("greyColor", true)
            Black: @Html.CheckBox("blackColor", true)
            Music: @Html.CheckBox("musicColor", true)
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>
                Obj Values: Select a value in the list below.
            </label>
            Obj Number: <input type="number" min="0" max="9999" name="cardNumber" value="int" style="width: 70px"/><br/>
            Additional Cost (contains): @Html.DropDownList("addCost", String.Empty) + @Html.DropDownList("addCost2", String.Empty)
            + @Html.DropDownList("addCost3", String.Empty) + @Html.DropDownList("addCost4", String.Empty)
            + @Html.DropDownList("addCost5", String.Empty) + @Html.DropDownList("addCost6", String.Empty)  <br/>
            Cost: @Html.DropDownList("objCostSymbol", "=") @Html.DropDownList("objCost", String.Empty)<br />
            Power: @Html.DropDownList("powerSymbol", "=") @Html.DropDownList("powerValue", String.Empty)<br/>
            Rating: @Html.DropDownList("ratingSymbol", "=") @Html.DropDownList("ratingValue", String.Empty)<br />
            <label>
                Obj Text: Write a name, part of a name, or a word.
            </label>
            Obj Name: @Html.TextBox("objName") <br/>
            Owner: @Html.TextBox("ownerName") <br />
            <label>
                Obj Categories: Select a category in the list below.
            </label>
            Type: @Html.DropDownList("objType","All") <br/>
            Obj Set: @Html.DropDownList("objSet", "All") <br/>
            Rarity: @Html.DropDownList("objRarity", "All")<br />
            <div class="float-right">
                <input type="submit" value="Filter" name="submitbutton">
            </div>
        </p>
    }
</p>
<span style="color:red; font-size: 1.7em; font-style: italic;">@ViewData["ErrorMessage"]</span>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Obj Name</th>
        <th>Obj Number</th>
        <th>Obj Color</th>
        <th>Additional Cost</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Obj Type</th>
        <th>@Html.ActionLink("Power", "SearchIndex", new {sortOrder=ViewBag.PowerSortParm})</th>
        <th>@Html.ActionLink("Rating", "SearchIndex", new {sortOrder=ViewBag.RatingSortParm})</th>
        <th>Rarity</th>
        <th>Obj Set Name</th>
        <th>Owner Name</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ObjName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ObjNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ObjColor)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ObjAddCost)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ObjCost)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ObjType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ObjPower)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ObjRating)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ObjRarity)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ObjSet.m_ObjSetName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ObjOwner)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.m_ObjID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.m_ObjID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.m_ObjID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<div>
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
    of @Model.PageCount

    @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<<", "SearchIndex", new {page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort})
        @Html.Raw(" ")
        @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "SearchIndex", new {page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort})
    }
    else
    {
        @:<<
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @:< Prev
    }

    @if (Model.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "SearchIndex", new {page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort})
        @Html.Raw(" ")
        @Html.ActionLink(">>", "SearchIndex", new {page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort})
    }
    else
    {
        @:Next >
        @Html.Raw(" ")
        @:>>
    }
</div>
```

Any advice will help me do a better job, thank you.

Comment: That's a _lot_ of function arguments.  Have you considered creating a single object which has the search parameters and just passing that object to the function?

Comment: Hum. Well, up to now, I'm creating an object based on each parameters. But my object used in the view is not the same as the one used. Here's the top of my view: '@model PagedList.IPagedList<MvcApp.Models.ObjInfo>'

Comment: Are the values given as part of the URL and sorted out via rotes in Global.asax, or are they part of a query string? If part of a query string, you can get rid of the parameters and use `Request.QueryString` to get at them (it will only include the values that are actually provided).

Comment: Ok, ok, I need to put my view too so that you understand what I'm doing. Pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but having the whole package will help you out.

Comment: @HerveS: I don't know what an `ObjInfo` is.  However, the model which populates the view has nothing to do with the model which is sent to the controller action.  As long as the values being sent to the server (I'm assuming in a form post in this case) have the right names and types to construct an instance of a particular object, that object can be used in that action method.  The model binder only cares about what's coming in, not what previously went out.

Comment: @David what puzzles me is that I have an object called `SearchObjInfo` which can hold all these values. But I am sending another object, the `ObjInfo`, to the view. How can I get back the `SearchObjInfo`? By adding the object as a property in the `ObjInfo` and using all the fields in the view?

Comment: if you do in fact have a SearchObjInfo, then you should pass that as a model to your view, not @model PagedList.IPagedList<MvcApp.Models.ObjInfo>. Then you can use an ajax /jQuery to post the values to the controller and get the results. I can expand on that if you're willing to take that route.

Answer (score 1):

Ho do you normally face this in JavaScript ? You would create an `option` object, like

```
var op = {
   cardName : "..",
   cardType : "" ,
    ...
}
```

and pass it to a function. Correct ?

The same do in `C#` too. 
Define a, say, `Conditions` class, like

```
public class Conditions {
    public string CardName {get;set;}
    public string CardType {get;set;}
    .. 
}
```

and pass it to your function, which controls the values of the properties of that type to act accordingly after.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not use `ModelBinder` . I think it's very useful with your case. Please see below:

_ I have a `Model`:

```
public class Employee
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
   public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

and `ModelBinder` for `Employee`:

```
public class EmployeeBinder : IModelBinder {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
            var emp = new Employee {
                                       Id = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Id"],
                                       FirstName = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["FirstName"],
                                       LastName = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["LastName"],
                                       BirthDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["year"]),
                                           int.Parse(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["month"]),
                                           int.Parse(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["day"]))
                                   };

            return emp;
        }
    }
```

Then `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult Example(Employee emp) {
            return View(emp);
}
```

URL: `http://localhost:1034/Home/Example?Id=1&LastName=lazycatit`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could handle your problem.

First, create a ViewModel with your search parameters.

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    public string ObjName { get; set; }
    public string ObjType { get; set; }
    public string OtherType { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, pass this to the view.

```
public virtual ActionResult SearchResults()
{
    return View(new FilterViewModel());
}
```

In your SearchResults.cshtml you need to encode the model to a json and then use an ajax call to filter your results. Assumming there's a button with btnFilterResults id. This is going to load the results from a partial view (that should be your table) using ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var dataViewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

    $("#btnFilterResults").click(function () {
        dataViewModel.ObjName = $("#objName").val(); //Make sure the ids corresponde to your html. 
        dataViewModel.ObjType = $("#objType").val();
        dataViewModel.OtherType = $("#otherType").val();

        $.ajax({
           url: "@Url.Action(MVC.ControllerName.GetSearchResults())",
           data: { viewModel: JSON.stringify(dataViewModel) },
           success: function(data) {
               $("#tableDiv").empty(); //
               $("#tableDiv").html(data);
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Finally, in your controller you can get the results:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult LoadTableReporteGeneral(string viewModel)
{
    var filterOptions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FilterViewModel>(viewModel);
    var query = from t in db.YourTableName
                select t;
     //This returns an IQueryable with all of your data, no filtering yet.

     //Start filtering.
     if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterOptions.ObjName))
     {
         query = query.Where(x => x.ObjName == filterOptions.ObjName);
     }  
     if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterOptions.ObjType ))
     {
         query = query.Where(x => x.ObjType == filterOptions.ObjType );
     }  
     //and so on. 
     //Finally return a partial view with your table. 
     return PartialView(MVC.Shared.Views._YourTableName, query);
}
```

Note: I'm using T4MVC and Json.Net packages.

Hope this helps.