# How to display create form in an existing MVC 4 view and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have view to display  Restaurant. In this view at the bottom of the page, I want to display Comments form to add comments about that Restaurant.

Can someone please help me to do this using MVC 4 & C#.

**My Models has the followign two tables:**

```
/Classifieds TABLE
public class Classifieds
{
    [Key]
    public string C_Unique_Id { get; set; }

    public string AdType { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
```

}

```
//ClassifiedsComments TABLE
public class ClassifiedsComments
    {
        [Key]
        public string CCommentsUniqueId { get; set; }

        public string CommentAuthor { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Classifieds")]
        public string C_Unique_Id { get; set; }   //this is the foreign key of Classified record
        public virtual Classifieds Classifieds { get; set; }
    }
```

**Classifieds Details view:**

```
 @model SomeIndianShit.Models.Classifieds

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

                <table class="recordDetailsDisplayTableStype">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="left">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description) 
                            <br /><br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Ad Type
                        </td>
                        <td align="left"> :
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AdType)
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    SOME OTHER FIELDS DISPLAY HERE
                </table>


//Here I want to display "ClassifiedsComments" form to add comments to above Classified.
//HOW can I display the ClassifiedsComments create.cshtml code here??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display data in view create view model, but to post comment, dont use model:

```
public class ClassifiedsViewModel
{
  public ClassifiedsViewModel()
  {
     Comments = new List<ClassifiedsComments>();
  }

  public Classifieds Classifieds { get; set; }
  public List<ClassifiedsComments> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Fill this view model, use in view to display details and comments like above you write.

```
if(Model != null && Model.Classifieds != null)
{
  <table> ...display details.. </table>
}

if(Model != null && Model.Comments != null)
{
  <table> ...display comments with foreach loop.. </table>
}
```

And at bottom, create comment post form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveComment", "Controller", FormMethod.Post,                                   new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    //set to which Classifieds will this comment posted
    @Html.Hidden("C_Unique_Id", Model.Classifieds.C_Unique_Id)

    <fieldset>
        @Html.TextBox("Comment")

       //other fields ....

       <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Edit2:** View model creating:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{ 
    //add breakpoint here and follow any step.

    ClassifiedsViewModel viewModel = new ClassifiedsViewModel();
    viewModel.Classifieds = db.Classifieds.Find(id);
    viewModel.Comments = db.LoadCommentsByClassifiedsId(id); //create db method
    // or instead of this line use:
    viewModel.Comments = db.ClassifiedsComments.Where(e => e.C_Unique_Id == id).ToList();

    return(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: the view is fine but error message is displayed for Get Details method in controller. DO I HV TO USE Classifieds classifieds = db.Classifieds.Find(id);  or ClassifiedsViewModel classifiedsViewModel = db.ClassifiedsViewModel.Find(id);

Comment: If i use ClassifiedsViewModel classifiedsViewModel = db.ClassifiedsViewModel.Find(id); and find elements in Details view as Model.Classifieds.C_Unique_Id  === blank page is displayed

Comment: If i use Classifieds classifieds = db.Classifieds.Find(id); in Details method in controller, error message displayed as "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SomeIndianShit.Models.Classifieds', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SomeIndianShit.Models.ClassifiedsViewModel'."

Comment: I edited my answer and i advise you to define unique id as "int" not "string"

Comment: Hi Jhoon, Thank you very much for your help. Able to display the Classifieds. I cant define the unique as INT as It is breaking my whole solution. Can you please let me know how can I fix the viewModel.ClassifiedsComments = db.ClassifiedsComments.Where(e => e.C_Unique_Id == id); as I am gettign error message here saying " Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<SomeIndianShit.Models.ClassifiedsComments>' to 'SomeIndianShit.Models.ClassifiedsComments'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)?"

Comment: it is casting problem, Oh, I have a misatake in view model, comments must be list; I edit view model, just now. Then after searching add '.ToList()' end of line

Comment: Hi Jhoon, with this new code, I am not able to find the elements to display in Details.cshtml view (@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ClassifiedsComments.Comment)) - giving an error message here saying "....does not contain a definition for Comment and no extension method...."

Comment: I think the problem is with @model SomeIndianShit.Models.ClassifiedsViewModel in Details.cshtml view. I need to add List here but it does not work for Classifieds..

Comment: You will not add view model list. will add only view model. it contains model self and comments list

Comment: Sorry so what is the issue here.. I did not understand it yet.

Comment: Hi Jhoon, I really appreciate your help. can you please help me to fix it

Comment: What error do you get? in what line, file? I edited answer, add a breakpoint and lets see where is problem

Comment: Hi Jhoon, If i declare int id, my whole solution is breaking. If declare as string id, and follow as above code, in View: Details.cshtml model => model.Comments.Comment is not available. Comments object is does not contain any values in it. Although Comment object have all the values in Controller when I debug with breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

With View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Classifieds", "ClassifiedsDetails", FormMethod.Post))
```

and

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ClassifiedsComments", "ClassifiedsDetails", FormMethod.Post))
```

And use 1 Model for this:

```
public class ClassifiedsDetails
{
    public Classifieds Model1{ get; set; }

    public ClassifiedsComments Model2{ get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

```
public class ClassifiedsDetails
{
    public ClassifiedsDetails()
    {
      Model1 = new Classifieds();
      Model2 = new ClassifiedsComments();
    }
    public Classifieds Model1{ get; set; }   
    public ClassifiedsComments Model2{ get; set; }
}

public class Classifieds
{
   public Classifieds()
   {
     C_Unique_Id = String.Emty;
     AdType = String.Emty;
     //---- Add default setting here------
   }
    [Key]
    public string C_Unique_Id { get; set; }

    public string AdType { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Or display list of comments in View with Model:

```
public class ClassifiedsDetails
    {
        public ClassifiedsDetails()
        {
          Model1 = new Classifieds();
          Model2 = new List<ClassifiedsComments>();
        }
        public Classifieds Model1{ get; set; }   
        public List<ClassifiedsComments> Model2{ get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model ClassifiedsDetails

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model1.Title)

@foreach (var items in Model.Model2)
{
   @item. //fields
}
```

Comment: I added same as above but in my Index controller object is coming as NULL.  GET: /Classifieds/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(string id = null)
        {
            ClassifiedsDetails classifiedsdetails = db.ClassifiedsDetails.Find(id);

Comment: In the above comment, classifiedsdetails  is coming as NULL

Comment: I think when use Model, you need declare a constructor, it will avoid a NULL exception or use ModelBinder with my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046178/how-to-deal-with-many-possible-values-to-make-a-query/16053763#16053763

Comment: Or use Ajax Form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor

Answer (score 0):

You can then add a ViewModel like this

```
public class ClassifiedsDetailViewModel
{
  public ClassifiedsDetailViewModel()
  {
      ClassifiedsComments = new ClassifiedsComments();
  }

  public Classifieds Classifieds { get; set; }
  public ClassifiedsComments ClassifiedsComments { get; set; }
}
```

Pass this view model to your view and then add @Html.Partial("_CreateClassifiedsCommentsFormPartial", Model.ClassifiedComments) below the table. And in your partial view, you can use Html.BeginForm or the Ajax.BeginForm.
[See sample here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC3)

Comment: An error message is displayed as "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'xyz.Models.Classifieds', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'xyz.Models.ClassifiedsComments'." 

Here is what I did:

-Added @Html.Partial("_CreateClassifiedsCommentsFormPartial") in Classifieds view

Comment: Add this in your Classifieds class...
    public ICollection<ClassifiedsComments> ClassifiedsComments { get; set; }

then replace @Html.Partial("_CreateClassifiedsCommentsFormPartial") with
@Html.Partial("_CreateClassifiedsCommentsFormPartial", Model.ClassifiedsComments)

Comment: Classifieds class means Classifieds Details Controller or Model class??

Comment: still getting an error message as "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SomeIndianShit.Models.Classifieds', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SomeIndianShit.Models.ClassifiedsComments'." at @Html.Partial("_CreateClassifiedsCommentsFormPartial", Model.ClassifiedsComments)

Comment: or should I need a IEnumerable instead of ICollection

Comment: Make sure that in your _CreateClassifiedsCommentsFormPartial, you have the correct model.. @model ClassifiedsComments